# error with PHP GLOBALS

Tags: php, global

I'm trying to store an array in a PHP GLOBAL like so:

```
// file_1.php

include 'functions/session_metrics.php';

$project_data = array();
$session_data = array();

if (isset($_GET["product"])) {

    $product = explode("|", $_GET["product"]);

    foreach ($product as $id) {
            list($project, $sessions) = getProductInfo( $id );
            $project_data[$id] = $project;
            $session_data[$id] = $sessions;
    }

    $GLOBALS['project_data'] = $project_data;
    $GLOBALS['session_data'] = $session_data;

}
```

Now from **another file** I'm trying to retireve it like so:

```
// file_2.php

$data= $GLOBALS['project_data']; 
print_r($data);
```

But I see the error:

```
Undefined Index: project_data...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: $globals is for single-thread use. It doesn't work between pages. So if one of your files isn't included inside the other file, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use native php `$_SESSION` to store session data:

```
$_SESSION['that'] = 'this';

echo $_SESSION['that']; //echoes `this`
```

Also by doing this: `$GLOBALS['session_data'] = $session_data;` you are setting a value equal to itself (which is implicit) unless `$session_data` is inside of a function.

Comment: it's my poor example...bad variable names.  They are not actual sessions.

Comment: @Paul then **what** are you trying to do?

Comment: Neal: I'm trying to pass a hashtable around to use in other scripts.  It contains data retrieved from my DB that I don't want to keep making.

Comment: @Paul so save to a session or to a file.

Comment: @Paul, if you're using `include` or `require` the variables will be "passed"... Paste a code example if you'd like more help.

Comment: Neal: I can pass a data structure via a session? I thought sessions were just for simple variables.

Comment: Neal: Thanks, I didn't know that would work. Plugged in sessions and it's working great!

Answer (score 0):

Most of time you have to pass the data to another file the same way you passed it into current.

So, if you use GET for the file_1.php, most likely you will need to pass the same parameter to the file_2.php.

It is way more common way, unlike sessions which have very limited use.

Answer (score -1):

The other file is not seeing the 'session_data' variable. Also it is very risky using globals like that, which is why PHP has completely dropped it out of their language as of PHP 5.4 and have it deprecated in PHP 5.3.

As stated above, you should use the $_SESSION variable to pass info from one file to another.

You can do so by:

```
# Start the sessions 
session_start();
#Set the session_data
$_SESSION['session_data'] = $sessions;
#retrieve data
$sessions = $_SESSION['session_data'];
```